# modifying data inside xml using ansible xml module

Tags: xml, ansible

I have an xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <!-- various other xml -->
   <database   name="cheyenne" driver="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" dbtype="DB2"
               url="jdbc:as400:unidb;date format=iso" schema="AR211009" user="ar211009"
               password="" passwordfile="XXXXXXXXXXXX" > </database>
   <!-- various other xml -->
</root>
```

and I want to edit and change the passwordfile value. Can someone show me an example on how to?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the documentation:

```yaml
- xml:
    path: '/path/to/your.xml'
    xpath: '/root/database'
    attribute: 'passwordfile'
    value: '/path/to/secret'
```

Comment: Schneider, Thanks for your post. I was over complicating from my side. I saw my mistake already. Now all works as expected